# ListView ViewHolder item child View visibility changing

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm having a `ListView` with a custom `ArrayAdapter`. The problem is that I cannot hide (`setVisibility(View.GONE)`) `TextView` in some elements of choice. Here is a minimized-readable summary part of my code:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemModel> {

    private int listItemLayout;

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView description;
    }

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List<ItemModel> itemList) {
        super(context, layoutId, itemList);
        this.listItemLayout = layoutId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemModel item = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(listItemLayout, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_desription);
        viewHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDescription())) {
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I hide a view inside item in `ListView` if its content `String` is empty?

Comment: maybe description is never empty?

Comment: Did you try putting that visibility code outside the if condition first try doing that if putting it outside if condition doesn't work then i would recommend you to put that code inside runonui thread

Comment: Did you check "TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDescription())" in debug mode? Maybe you can change your approach. You can check description by (item.getDescription().equals("")) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add else part of if condition to change visibility from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` as in below code.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private int listItemLayout;

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView description;
    }

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List itemList) {
        super(context, layoutId, itemList);
        this.listItemLayout = layoutId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemModel item = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(listItemLayout, parent, false);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_desription);
        viewHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDescription())) {
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

OR
 try  `if (item.getDescription()==null || item.getDescription().trim().length() == 0)`
instead of `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDescription()))`

Answer (score 1):

Check any white space should not be in your text. Try this-

```
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDescription().trim()) ||item.getDescription().trim().length()==0 ) {
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    else{
       viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
```